# How to use distinct and where clause together in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe and list as given below

```
op1 = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,2,3,4,4,5],
'iid': [21,22,23,24,26,26,27],
'los':[121,122,123,124,111,111,131],
'area':['a','a','b','c','d','d','f'],
'date' : ['1/1/2017','1/2/2017','1/3/2017','1/4/2017','1/6/2017','1/6/2017','1/8/2109'],
'val' :[5,10,5,16,26,26,7]
 })

sub_list = [1,2,3,4]
```

I would like to check whether the `subject_id` from `sub_list` is present in `op1`. If present, then get the `distinct` values from columns `los`,`iid`,`area` for that subject_id (look for difference between `subject_id` `1` `and` `4` (which has duplicates)

I tried the below but couldn't have multiple columns

```
op1[op1['subject_id'].isin(sub_list)] # how to use distinct records here?
```

I have to apply this to a million records. So any elegant and efficient solution is helpful

I am looking for something like

```
select distinct subject_id, iid,los, area from op1
where subject_id in [sub_list]
```

I expect my output to be as shown below

[image]

Comment: All the answers below were really good. However I can mark one answer as solution. So, I go with GZ0 answer as it met the expected output condition. Nonetheless other answers are also upvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you intend to return only the selected columns, do this:

```
result = op1.loc[op1["subject_id"].isin(sub_list), ["subject_id", "los", "iid", "area"]].drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Upvoted. Yes, I expect to return only those columns.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how fast this is, but you can try:

```
(op1[['subject_id','iid','los','area']]
     .drop_duplicates(['subject_id','iid','los','area'])
     .set_index('subject_id')
     .loc[sub_list]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
op1[op1['subject_id'].isin(sub_list)].drop_duplicates(subset=list_columns_to_distinct)
```

Comment: But how do I select only few columns?. I would like to check for duplicates only in specific columns. Hence distinct

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a mix of the previous answers

```py
distCols = ["subject_id", "iid",
            "los", "area"]

op1[op1['subject_id'].isin(sub_list)].drop_duplicates(distCols)
```